# взять число из строки и записать в другую

Tags: javascript, html

Сайт из 3 страниц: на первой странице поле для ввода, на второй - анимация загрузки (после загрузки перекидывает на третью), на третьей - поле, в котором необходим результат введенного в поле 1 страницы, плюс/минус 15%? По возможности полный код и можно ли вообще это сделать?

Получается реализовать только попапом на одной странице, используя:

```
document.write('Результат: ',+prompt('ввод значения:')*1.15)
```

Comment: "... как сделать ... "(с) Написать плагин к браузеру, который будет копировать поле ввода и устанавливать значение в третье окно

Comment: Используй localStorage и запиши значение туда, а на последней странице достань